# I am using a rich text editor that inserts images into mysqli database, I want to extract images into files

Tags: php, image-processing, mysqli

I'm using Summernote editor to collect user input, during this process users can insert images, the image data is then saved into mysql database using PHP & SQL,  I want the ability to extract the file(s) from the database record, save the image then replace the image with url as an image tag.

I cannot find any posts that show how this can be achieved.

Here is a cut down from example record.

```
<p><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJoAAACaCAYAAABR/1EXAAAABGdBTUEAALGOfPtRkwAAACBjSFJNAACHDwAAjA8AAP1SAACBQAAAfXkAAOmLAAA85QAAGcxzPIV3AAAKLD9k7w7ivJbRkANSszRi8CgzmrKVwMC0gHCJi5PR/OcAiiQZFWxGqZuPIyGm3LhH6UtvKacCYyheltOgEH7xEcnsLp9JT0WVzEskyMItDViixhrypx0LCOARwc40pM8FunWS/T70+V/wPr/bssGCXNzQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" data-filename="alisonD_154x154.png" style="width: 25%;"><br></p>
```

To summarise, I want to be able to post process SQL records, when find images embedded, to save the data as an image file, replace the embedded image with a url which will point to the saved file.

Comment: It sounds like you have a general idea of the steps to be performed... so where are you stuck?  What have you tried that isn't working?  You're very unlikely to find an existing solution that does *exactly* what you want that you can just copy and paste.  So start building your solution.  When you try, where specifically do you get stuck?

Comment: Thanks John for fixing my post.

Comment: I have good skills with PHP and very good with adapting/modifying scripts, I cannot find any posts which show how to extract files from a database record.  The only method I can think of is to use sequential read until find start/end tags for images, there must be an easier way.

Comment: "Extract a file from a database record" is far too broad and somewhat meaningless.  If what you have in your data is an HTML string, then your starting point is that HTML string.  You can use a DOM Parser to get the specific HTML element(s) you're looking for and read their attributes.  Then you'll have the `src` attributes of your images as base-64 encoded data.  From there, convert that to a binary file.  Etc.  Etc.  Don't look for a single method to accomplish the entire end-to-end process, write code to accomplish eash step.

Comment: Thanks David, the  image is embedded as shown in the cut-down code above, I do have src="image code etc.....",  I have never used a DOM parser, so guess I will have to research this.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks david, you pointed me in the direction I needed, I will solve my problem using PHP DOM Parser.  I've located this post which has the full solution.

[Parse web pages with PHP Simple DOM Parser](https://davidwalsh.name/php-notifications)